# Stuck in gmap intregration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-5.3

Here I am integrating gmap in my laravel project and want to show locations with some info on gmap but map is not working as expected. there is an issue in showing the map and map is also not displayed. here I am attaching image how exactly it looks. [image]

also I will show code and relate js

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Checkbox & radio inputs
     */
    $('input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').ezMark();

    /**
     * Map Leaflet Contact
     */
    if ($('#map-contact').length) {
        var map = L.map('map-contact', {
            zoom: 12,
            maxZoom: 20,
            center: [40.761077, -73.88]
        });         

        map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
        var access_token = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw';

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=' + access_token, {      
            scrollWheelZoom: false,     
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
            attribution: '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
        }).addTo(map);  

        var icon = L.divIcon({
            html: '<i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>',
            iconSize: [36, 36],
            iconAnchor: [36, 36],
            popupAnchor: [-20, -42]
        });

        var marker = L.marker([40.761077, -73.88], {
            icon: icon
        }).addTo(map);  
    }

    /**
     * Map Leaflet
     */
    if ($('#map-leaflet').length) {
        var map = L.map('map-leaflet', {
            zoom: 12,
            maxZoom: 20,
            center: [40.761077, -73.88]
        }); 

        var access_token = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw';
        var marker_cluster = L.markerClusterGroup();        

        map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=' + access_token, {      
            scrollWheelZoom: false,     
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
            attribution: '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
        }).addTo(map);

        $.ajax('assets/data/markers.json', {
            success: function(markers) {
                $.each(markers, function(index, value) {
                    var icon = L.divIcon({
                        html: value.icon,
                        iconSize:     [36, 36],
                        iconAnchor:   [36, 36],
                        popupAnchor:  [-20, -42]
                    });

                    var marker = L.marker(value.center, {
                        icon: icon
                    }).addTo(map);      

                    marker.bindPopup(
                        '<div class="listing-window-image-wrapper">' +
                            '<a href="properties-detail-standard.html">' +
                                '<div class="listing-window-image" style="background-image: url(' + value.image + ');"></div>' +
                                '<div class="listing-window-content">' +
                                    '<div class="info">' +
                                        '<h2>' + value.title + '</h2>' +
                                        '<h3>' + value.price + '</h3>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</a>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );

                    marker_cluster.addLayer(marker);
                });

                map.addLayer(marker_cluster);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Google Map
     */
    if ($('#map-google').length) {
        $.ajax('assets/data/markers.json', {
            "dataType" : "json",
            success: function(values) {
                var markers = [];
                var infos = [];

                $.each(values, function(index, value) {
                    var content = '<div id="' + value.id + '" class="map-popup-content-wrapper"><div class="map-popup-content"><div class="listing-window-image-wrapper">' +
                            '<a href="properties-detail-standard.html">' +
                                '<div class="listing-window-image" style="background-image: url(' + value.image + ');"></div>' +
                                '<div class="listing-window-content">' +
                                    '<div class="info">' +
                                        '<h2>' + value.title + '</h2>' +
                                        '<h3>' + value.price + '</h3>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</a>' +
                        '</div></div><i class="fa fa-close close"></i></div>' +
                        '<div class="map-marker">' + value.icon + '</div>';

                    markers.push({
                        latLng: value.center, 
                        data: value.id,         
                        options: {                                  
                            content: content,
                            offset: {
                                x: -18,
                                y: -42
                            }                           
                        }
                    });
                });

                $('#map-google').gmap3({        
                    map: {                                  
                        options:{
                            styles: [{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#FFBB00"},{"saturation":43.400000000000006},{"lightness":37.599999999999994},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#00FF6A"},{"saturation":-1.0989010989011234},{"lightness":11.200000000000017},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#FFC200"},{"saturation":-61.8},{"lightness":45.599999999999994},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#FF0300"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":51.19999999999999},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#FF0300"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":52},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#0078FF"},{"saturation":-13.200000000000003},{"lightness":2.4000000000000057},{"gamma":1}]}],
                            center:[40.761077, -73.88],
                            scrollwheel: false,
                            zoom: 12
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        cluster: {
                            radius: 100,
                        }
                    },
                    overlay: {
                        values: markers,
                        events: {
                            click: function(marker, event, context) {                                                           
                                $('.map-popup-content-wrapper').css('display', 'none');

                                if ($(event[0].target).hasClass('close')) {
                                    $('#' + context.data).css('display', 'none');
                                } else {
                                    $('#' + context.data).css('display', 'block');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });                 
            }       
        });
    }

    /**
     * Properties Carousel
     */
     $('.listing-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 4,
        margin: 30,
        nav: true,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            540: {
                items: 2
            },  
            766: {
                items: 2
            },
            990: {
                items: 3
            },
            1200: {
                items: 4
            }           
        }
     });

    /**
     * Cover carousel
     */
     $('.cover-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        nav: true,
        navText: ['<img src="assets/img/lnr-chevron-left.svg" alt="">', '<img src="assets/img/lnr-chevron-right.svg" alt="">']
     });

    /**
     * Image gallery
     */
     $('.gallery').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: 3000,
        items: 1,
        nav: true,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>']
     });

    /**
     * Customizer
     */  
    $('.customizer-title').on('click', function() {     
        $('.customizer').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $('.customizer a').click('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var cssFile = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#css-primary').attr('href', cssFile);
    });

    /**
     * Charts
     */
    if ($('.ct-chart-1').length) {
        var data = {
            labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            series: [
                [5, 4, 3, 7, 5, 10, 3, 4, 8, 10, 6, 8],
                [3, 2, 9, 5, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4]
            ]
        };

        var options = {
            seriesBarDistance: 15
        };

        var responsiveOptions = [
            ['screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1024px)', {
                seriesBarDistance: 10,
                axisX: {
                    labelInterpolationFnc: function (value) {
                        return value;
                    }
                }
            }],
            ['screen and (max-width: 640px)', {
                seriesBarDistance: 5,
                axisX: {
                    labelInterpolationFnc: function (value) {
                        return value[0];
                    }
                }
            }]
        ];

        new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart-1', data, options, responsiveOptions);
    }

    /**
     * Charts
     */
    if ($('.ct-chart-2').length) {
        new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart-2', {
            labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
            series: [
                [1, 2, 3, 1, -2, 0, 1, 0],
                [-2, -1, -2, -1, -2.5, -1, -2, -1],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2.5, 2, 1],
                [2.5, 2, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, -1, -2.5]
            ]
        }, {
            high: 3,
            low: -3,
            showArea: true,
            showLine: false,
            showPoint: false,
            fullWidth: true,
            axisX: {
                showLabel: false,
                showGrid: false
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Charts
     */
    if ($('.ct-chart-3').length) {
        new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart-3', {
            labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
            series: [
                [5, 4, 3, 7, 5, 10, 3],
                [3, 2, 9, 5, 4, 6, 4]
            ]
        }, {
            seriesBarDistance: 10,
            reverseData: true,
            horizontalBars: true,
            axisY: {
                offset: 70
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Charts
     */
    if ($('.ct-chart-4').length) {
        var times = function(n) {
            return Array.apply(null, new Array(n));
        };

        var data = times(52).map(Math.random).reduce(function(data, rnd, index) {
            data.labels.push(index + 1);
            data.series.forEach(function(series) {
                series.push(Math.random() * 100)
            });

            return data;
        }, {
            labels: [],
            series: times(4).map(function() { return new Array() })
        });

        var options = {
            showLine: false,
            axisX: {
                labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
                    return index % 13 === 0 ? 'W' + value : null;
                }
            }
        };

        var responsiveOptions = [
            ['screen and (min-width: 640px)', {
                axisX: {
                    labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
                        return index % 4 === 0 ? 'W' + value : null;
                    }
                }
            }]
        ];

        new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart-4', data, options, responsiveOptions);
    }
});
```

and this is a view file **properties.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <link href="https:://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway::300,400,500,600,300,700&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/libraries/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/libraries/chartist/chartist.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/leaflet.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/leaflet.markercluster.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/leaflet.markercluster.default.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/villareal-blue.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="css-primary">
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/overwrite-home.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="css-primary">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/favicon.png') }}">

    <title>Houzeo - Properties Map</title>
</head>

<body class="">
<div class="page-wrapper">

        <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header header-small">
        <div class="header-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="header-top">
                    <div class="header-top-inner">
                        <span class="header-logo-text"><a class="header-logo" href="index.html"> <img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/hou-imgs/houzeologo.png')}}" alt="HOUZEO LOGO"> </a></span>
                        <!-- /.header-logo -->

                         <a class="header-action" href="properties-submit.html">
                            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> <span>Upload Property</span>
                        </a><!-- /.header-action -->
                        </button> -->                       
                    </div><!-- /.header-top-inner -->
                </div><!-- /.header-top -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div><!-- /.header-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.header -->
</div><!-- /.header-wrapper-->      


    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="main-inner">

                <div class="content">

                    <div class="container-fluid fullwidth-wrapper map-and-property-holder">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mapProperty-holder">
                                @foreach($list as $item)
                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="listingbox">
                                            <div class="listing-box-image" style="background-image:url('assets/img/tmp/tmp-5.jpg')">
                                                <span class="listing-box-image-links listing-box-over"> 
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span>View Property Dashboard</span></a> 
                                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span>View Listing</span></a> 
                                                </span>     
                                            </div><!-- /.listing-box-image -->

                                            <div class="listing-box-title">
                                                <h2><a href="properties-detail-standard.html">Bright Island Route</a></h2>
                                                <h3>$ 40.000</h3>
                                            </div><!-- /.listing-box-title -->

                                            <div class="listing-box-content">
                                                <dl>
                                                    <dt>Type</dt><dd>House</dd>
                                                    <dt>Location</dt><dd>New York</dd>
                                                    <dt>Area</dt><dd>180 sqft</dd>
                                                </dl>
                                            </div><!-- /.listing-box-cotntent -->
                                        </div><!-- /.listing-box -->
                                    </div><!-- /.col-* -->      
                                </div>
                                @endforeach


                            </div><!-- /.col-* -->

                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 map-holder">
                                    <div id="map-leaflet" class="full"></div>
                                        <!--Please insert your map here.-->

                                </div>


                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                    </div><!-- /.container -->
                </div><!-- /.content -->
            </div><!-- /.main-inner -->
        </div><!-- /.main -->
    </div><!-- /.main-wrapper -->
</div><!-- /.page-wrapper -->


 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyASlnVdH_6j-XibxbQoeV82oZQImV1a_Vs"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.ezmark.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/tether.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/gmap3.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/leaflet.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/leaflet.markercluster.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/libraries/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/libraries/chartist/chartist.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/scrollPosStyler.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/villareal.js')}}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using Google Maps or Mapbox? You are using both in your question...

Comment: Is the remote script loaded? Checked your favorite browser's `Network` tab?

Comment: @Terry I think thats the problem . What should I do

Comment: yes remote script is loaded @kerbholz

Comment: Any errors in the console of your browser ?

Comment: no . no any error @Baptiste

Comment: It looks like your creating the same map multiple time. Maybe have a different name for the second map instead of using the same name ?

Comment: Where did you see that I am using map multiple times. can you help me with code ?? @Baptiste

Comment: can somebody help me with this because I am on assignment which can secure my job ?? @kerbholz